# AudioContext Mute sound when setValueAtTime foreach still working

Tags: class, mute, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I have class `MorseCodeAudio` to create sound for Morse'a code. I'm using `window.AudioContext`. In my class I have an method with `forEach`:

```
morseCode() {
    // irrelevant code

    this.text.split('').forEach(letter => {
        switch(letter) {
            case '.':
                this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, this.time)
                this.time += this.period
                this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, this.time)
                this.time += this.period
                break
            case '-':
                this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, this.time)
                this.time += 3 * this.period
                this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, this.time)
                this.time += this.period
                break
            case ' ':
                this.time += 7 * this.period
                break
        }
    })
}
```

And method to mute sound:

```
muteAudioMorse(muteValue) {
    if(this.audioCtx.state !== 'closed') this.gainNode.gain.value = muteValue
}
```

I can't mute the sound because forEach is still executing. If I remove forEach and add one line with sound, like this:

```
this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, 0)
```

then `muteAudioMorse` method work correctly.

How I can change `gain.value` when `setValueAtTime` from forEach still working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "mute" sound by `disconnect` and `connect`:

```
muteAudioMorse(muteValue) {
    if(this.audioCtx.state === 'running') {
        if(muteValue === 0) this.gainNode.disconnect(this.audioCtx.destination)
        else if(muteValue === 1) this.gainNode.connect(this.audioCtx.destination)
    }
}
```